# Post on Facebook via HtmlUnit

Tags: java, html, facebook, htmlunit

I looking for a "method" to post a message on facebook using HtmlUnit. I'd like to go to the wall page, and fill the text box:

```
HtmlTextInput text = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById(textBoxId);
text.setTextContent("Hello!");
```

I want to "click" on the Post button, but i can't figure out the way to select the button element and perform the action. Is there a way to do so?

Here's an explicative image: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an element doesn't contain an `id` attribute you can still get it using XPath. The HtmlUnit way of using [XPath](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) is by means of the [getFirstByXPath](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#getFirstByXPath%28java.lang.String%29) and [getByXPath](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#getByXPath%28java.lang.String%29) methods.

A short and over simplified example would be:

```
page.getFirstByXPath("//button[text()='Post']");
```

As a side note, you might be more interested in using the Facebook API rather than webscraping Facebook, which, by the way, is very likely to be against their terms of service.

Comment: I don't think it violate Facebook's term because doing that like you use a browser but not Firefox, Chrome,...

Comment: @dalmate It is not a matter of what *you think* but rather what *Facebook thinks*. After a quick Google search I've found their [terms of service](https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php) which states: _2. You will not engage in Automated Data Collection without Facebook's express written permission._